# EOF error when asking user for input in Python code

Tags: python, input, eoferror

The program "goofin.py" asks the user for a list and is supposed to remove the odd numbers from the list and print the new list out. Here is my code:

```
def remodds(lst):
    result = []
    for elem in lst:
        if elem % 2 == 0:          # if list element is even
            result.append(elem)    # add even list elements to the result 
    return result


justaskin = input("Give me a list and I'll tak out the odds: ") #this is 
                                                                #generates 
                                                                #an EOF 
                                                                #error

print(remodds(justaskin))      # supposed to print a list with only even-
                               # numbered elements


#I'm using Windows Powershell and Python 3.6 to run the code. Please help! 

#error message: 

#Traceback (most recent call last):
# File "goofin.py", line 13, in <module>
#    print(remodds(justaskin))
# File "goofin.py", line 4, in remodds
#    if elem % 2 == 0:
#TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Do you get the error before you have a chance to type anything, or after you hit enter, or at some other time?

Comment: I get the error when I run the program in the Windows Powershell. ie. after I hit enter

Comment: Post your error. In your question.

Comment: Place a `print(elem, type(elem))` in between `for elem in lst:
        if elem % 2 == 0:` and you will immediately see, what your problems are. Depending on, what you type in you have a) one problem that your `elem` is a string and b) that you have other list elements like `space`, `,` or `[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked fine for me:

```
def remodds(lst):
    inputted = list(lst)
    result = []
    for elem in inputted:
        if int(elem) % 2 == 0:          
            result.append(elem)
    return result


justaskin = input("Give me a list and I'll tak out the odds: ") 
print(remodds(justaskin))
```

My input:

```
15462625
```

My output:

```
['4', '6', '2', '6', '2']
```

explanation:

```
- convert the input (which was a string) to a list
- change the list element to an integer
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your input `lst` is not a list, even if you type in a list like `2, 13, 14, 7` or `2 13 14 7`. It is still one string, when you take it apart with your `elem` loop, meaning each individual character is one loop. You have to split `lst` first and convert them into numbers.

```
def remodds(lst):
    real_list = [int(x) for x in lst.split()]
    result = []
    for elem in real_list:           #and now the rest of your code
```

The split method uses at the moment the space between numbers, but you could also define, that the elements are separated for instance by a comma.

```
 real_list = [int(x) for x in lst.split(',')]
```